# Rails 4 - ActionView error - looking for template where there isn't one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview

I'm trying to figure out what an error message means. I am using statesman gem for states. One of my states is called 'requested'.

```
 state :requested, initial: :true 
  state :approved 
  state :rejected 
  state :removed 

  transition from: :requested, to: [ :approved, :rejected ]
  transition from: :approved, to: [ :removed ]
```

I have an index, listing all the states that an object can transition to:

```
<% if policy(orgReq).approved? %>    
                      <%= link_to "APPROVE", requested_organisation_request_path(orgReq), :class=>'btn btn-info', method: :put %>
                  <% end %>

                  <% if policy(orgReq).rejected? %>    
                      <%= link_to "DECLINE", decline_organisation_request_path(orgReq), :class=>'btn btn-info', method: :put %>
                  <% end %>

                  <% if policy(orgReq).removed? %>    
                      <%= link_to "REMOVE", removed_organisation_request_path(orgReq), :class=>'btn btn-info', method: :put %>
                  <% end %>
                </td>
```

I have a controller action for each state:

```
def requested
    # this is the initial state - there is nothing in the controller action
end
def approved
    organisation_request = OrganisationRequest.find(params[:id])
    authorize @organisation_request
    if organisation_request.state_machine.in_state?(:requested)
      flash[:notice] = "You've been added as a member. Welcome aboard."
      format.html { redirect_to :index }

    else
      flash[:error] = "You're not able to manage this organisation's members"
      redirect_to(profile_path(current_user.profile))

    end
  end

  def removed
    organisation_request = OrganisationRequest.find(params[:id])
    authorize @organisation_request
    if organisation_request.state_machine.in_state?(:approved)
      flash[:notice] = "Removed from the organisation."
      format.html { redirect_to :index }

    else
      flash[:error] = "You're not able to manage this organisation's members"
      redirect_to(profile_path(current_user.profile))

    end
  end
```

I don't understand what the error message below means? It comes when I try to click a button on the index to change the state of the object from requested to approved (which is an allowed transition).

Does anyone know how to interpret this error message?  Do I need to add something to the requested method in the controller?

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate at /organisation_requests/1/requested
Missing template organisation_requests/requested, application/requested with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
```

Comment: Rails is trying to render a HTML response to the click but there is no template describing the output. If you want the user to see a specific page, create the template; if not, you need to redirect in the response.

Comment: hmm - so the problem is that my requested action is empty in the controller.  requested is the initial state - i don't know what to write in there to make this error stop.

Comment: What do you want the user to see when they click that link?

Comment: it should just save as a request and the request is part of a form, the form has a submit button and an after submit redirect

Comment: I don't see the form code here - am I missing something? If the code is calling your (empty) action 'requested' there will not be any output without a template.